# ifthispageodd with scrlayer-notecolumn crashes LaTeX: Any workarounds for creating margin notes?

Tags: lyx, margins, koma-script, marginnote, scrbook

I'm currently working on a book project in LaTeX and LyX and found a weird bug that seems to **crash LaTeX**. I have no idea how to work around that crash, so I thought I'd ask for help here.

In a nutshell: I'm using the **KOMA-script** class `scrbook` to create a document of size A4 and would like to set up **margin notes** alongside the main text. I read a lot about different procedures for that and decided to try the `scrlayer-notecolumn` package to avoid the disadvantages of the other methods.

For greater clarity, I would like to be able to **indent** all regular paragraphs, but leave chapter and section headings unindented. I already managed to set that up (but I'm open for suggestions, in case this should be done differently). Here's a MWE for the class file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{MyBook}[2016/10/01 My Book Class]

% General setup
\RequirePackage{blindtext}
\RequirePackage{leading}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{color}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\newcommand\pagedividers{14}

% Page Layout
\LoadClass[
  a4paper,
  twoside,
  titlepage,
  fontsize = 9pt,
  parskip = full,
  headings = small,
  index = totoc,
  listof = totoc,
  bibliography = totoc,
  numbers = noenddot,
  appendixprefix = true,
  captions = nooneline
]{scrbook}

\RequirePackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  reversemarginpar,
  inner  = 21cm /  \pagedividers,
  outer  = 21cm / \pagedividers * 2,
  top    = 29.7cm / \pagedividers,
  bottom = 29.7cm / \pagedividers,
  heightrounded
}

% Use scrlayer-scrpage, so that package notecolumn works
\RequirePackage[
  plainheadsepline,
  plainfootsepline,
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% Set up the note column
\RequirePackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}
\RequirePackage{scrextend}
\newlength{\completemargin}
\setlength{\completemargin}{4.125cm}
\newlength{\notescolwidth}
\setlength{\notescolwidth}{\completemargin - \marginparsep}

\DeclareNewNoteColumn[
  marginpar,
  position = \ifthispageodd{\oddsidemargin + 1in}{\evensidemargin + 1in},
  width = \notescolwidth,
  font = \raggedright\footnotesize\color{orange}
]{notes}

% Indent the paragraphs, lists, equations and subsections
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\leftskip}{\completemargin}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin = \completemargin}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin = \completemargin}
\setlist[description]{leftmargin = \completemargin + 1cm, labelindent = \completemargin}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\setlength{\leftskip}{\completemargin}}
\addtokomafont{paragraph}{\setlength{\leftskip}{\completemargin}}
\addtokomafont{subparagraph}{\setlength{\leftskip}{\completemargin}}
\RequirePackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{\completemargin + 1cm}
```

And here's a sample file for testing the layout:

```
\documentclass[english]{MyBook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Heading}

\Blindtext[2]

\section{Section Heading}

\makenote[notes]{Here's a note for the new note column. Just for testing purposes.}\Blindtext[4]

\subsection{Sub Section Heading}

\makenote[notes]{Here's a note for the new note column. Just for testing purposes.}\Blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

This, of course, give me an asymmetrical layout. And here's where my problem starts:

The note column (`notes` in the above example) needs to be to the left of the main text, both on the odd and on the even pages. As the outer and inner margins are different, I need a way to check, if I'm on an odd or even page, when setting the position of the note column. I do this - as suggested - by using `\ifthispageodd` from package `scrextend`.

This, however, **crashes LaTeX** (or pdflatex, when called from LyX).

I'm really not sure how to work around that. If I remove `\ifthispageodd` and use, e.g., `\oddsidemargin` instead, the pages look like that:

[image: Position of note column should be the actual left page margin.]

So, is there any other way for checking odd or even pages? Or is there a command that I can use for reading out the actual left margin of the current page (instead of `\oddsidemargin` in the above MWE). Or should I use a different procedure for setting up the note column? Any help would be much appreciated.

Oh, by the way: If anybody has an idea how to **align** the baseline of the notes in the note column with the main text, I'd be very happy, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\Ifthispageodd`¹ uses a mechanism that is very similar to setting and referecing a label. This could be the reason why it crashes. But when a layer page style (which is used for the note column) is initialized, the correct page number is known. So you can use

```
  position = \ifodd\value{page}
               \dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin \relax
             \else
               \dimexpr 1in+\evensidemargin \relax
             \fi
```

Note that `\dimexpr` and `\relax` are not needed when package `calc` was loaded.

[image]
[image]

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{MyBook}[2016/10/01 My Book Class]

% General setup
\RequirePackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\RequirePackage{leading}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{color}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\newcommand\pagedividers{14}

% Page Layout
\LoadClass[
  a4paper,
  twoside,
  titlepage,
  fontsize = 9pt,
  parskip = full,
  headings = small,
  index = totoc,
  listof = totoc,
  bibliography = totoc,
  numbers = noenddot,
  appendixprefix = true,
  captions = nooneline
]{scrbook}

\RequirePackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  reversemarginpar,
  inner  = \paperwidth  / \pagedividers,
  outer  = \paperwidth  / \pagedividers * 2,
  top    = \paperheight / \pagedividers,
  bottom = \paperheight / \pagedividers,
  heightrounded
}

% Use scrlayer-scrpage, so that package notecolumn works
\RequirePackage[
  plainheadsepline,
  plainfootsepline,
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% Set up the note column
\RequirePackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}
\newlength{\completemargin}
\setlength{\completemargin}{4.125cm}
\newlength{\notescolwidth}
\setlength{\notescolwidth}{\completemargin - \marginparsep}

\DeclareNewNoteColumn[
  marginpar,
  position = \ifodd \value{page} 1in+\oddsidemargin \else 1in+\evensidemargin \fi,
  width = \notescolwidth,
  font = \raggedright\footnotesize\color{orange}
]{notes}

% Indent the paragraphs, lists, equations and subsections
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\leftskip}{\completemargin}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin = \completemargin}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin = \completemargin}
\setlist[description]{leftmargin = \completemargin + 1cm, labelindent = \completemargin}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    indent=\completemargin
    ]{subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
\RequirePackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{\completemargin + 1cm}
```

Note that I have used `\RedeclareSectionCommands` to change the indent of `subsubsection` etc.

```
\documentclass[english]{MyBook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Heading}
\Blindtext[2]

\section{Section Heading}
\leavevmode\makenote[notes]{Here's a note for the new note column. Just for testing purposes.}
\Blindtext[4]

\subsection{Sub Section Heading}
\leavevmode\makenote[notes]{Here's a note for the new note column. Just for testing purposes.}
\Blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

¹ Starting with KOMA-Script Version 3.28 `\ifthispageodd` was replaced by `\Ifthispageodd`.

Comment: Oh, thanks, that's a quite an elaborate idea. I kinda expected the problem to have a simpler solution and wouldn't have thought that this would necessitate setting up layers and two different note columns. Why isn't the same procedure necessary when positioning the note using, e.g., `\marginpar` (which renders the note on different positions depending on whether it's a right or a left page)? By the way: Does \ifthispageodd also crash your LaTeX (i.e. it never stops running, making it necessary to force-kill the process) or is that a bug in my installation?

Comment: You are absolutly right: there is no need to define an additional layer. You can simple use `\ifodd \value{page} ... \else ...\fi`. So I have changed my answer.